# What are the following constructs in Mono.Cecil referring to in C#?

Tags: c#, mono, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern, mono.cecil

Would someone explain what are these referring to?

```
MemberReference, TypeReference, ExternType, Override, NestedType,
PInvokeInfo, SecurityDeclaration and CustomAttribute and MarshalSpec
```

It would be ideal if you can illustrate with examples.

I am trying to write a visitor pattern in `Mono.Cecil`.

Answer (score 5):

Those terms represent the underlying ECMA Common Language Infrastructure terms.   The .NET Framework offers an abstract layer over those concepts.

You want to look at Partition III of the ECMA 335 specification:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513319/mono-cecil-documentation-and-tutorials/1706787#1706787